# what is this panel indicator/menu bar icon?

Tags: icons, indicator, menu, panel

Had this panel indicator pop up on my menu bar...anyone know what it is? The icon is a Satellite dish with a computer monitor. I've been looking around online but haven't found any info. My computer froze as soon as it popped up, and being new to Linux, I have no clue what it is. Sorry for the image quality, couldn't get it to focus very well, and sorry for the link, but being new I can't post images yet...

[image: screenshot]

Thanks.

Comment: Ok...I found it...it's Remmina, which is a remote desktop app, which now leads me to the task of finding out how this opened itself on my computer...

Answer (score 1):

It's Remmina Remote Desktop Client.

Although I don't think it is the culprit for the freezing, you can stop it from being launched at initialization by running on a terminal:

```
rm ~/.config/autostart/remmina-applet.desktop
```

Comment: Right on, thanks. My biggest concern now is how it got opened in the first place. I had been logged in for sometime before it appeared on my menu bar, and I simultaneously froze. Any short-cut keys that could have opened it maybe? Once I found it in my applications and opened it, everything ran fine so I dunno what the deal was. I was just watching some stuff on youtube when it opened. So if it wasn't an accidental key combination or something that opened it I am stumped. But no issues since.

Comment: @KhanFusion I don't know any key combination that launches Remmina, but I know that its default setting is to automatically run at startup. You have to go into "Preferences" and disable "Start tray icon automatically".